# Finding the law of $Z=\frac{X+Y}{2}$ given the law of X and Y.

Tags: probability

> Let be $X$ and $Y$ two independent random variables with integer even values. $X$ and $Y$  follows the same probability law:
>
> $$\forall k \in N, P(X=2k)=(k+1)*P(X=2k+2)$$
>
> determine the law of the random variable $Z=\frac{X+Y}{2}$

$$P(Z=\frac{X+Y}{2}=k)\Leftrightarrow P(X+Y=2k)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow P(X=m,Y=n), m+n=2k$$
$$=(\frac{m}{2}+1)P(X=\frac{2m+2}{2})(\frac{l}{2}+1)P(Y=\frac{2l+2}{2})$$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independant.

but I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction...
Have you got any hint helping me solving this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum over all $m$ such that $X=m$ and $Y=2k-m$, with the bounds for $m$ determined by the support for $X$, and $Y$ .  (Ie: $m\in 2\Bbb N \wedge (2k-m )\in 2\Bbb N$).  Since the supports are even integers, we'll use $m=2n$.

$$P(X+Y=2k) = \sum_{n=0}^{k} P(X=2n, Y=2k-2n) \mathsf 1_{k\in\Bbb N}$$

---

To find what $\mathsf P(X=2k)$ actually is, let $p_k \mathop{:=} \mathsf P(X=2k)$, so we have: $p_{k+1} = \frac 1{(k+1)} p_k$  and also $1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k$.

$$\begin{align}p_1 & = p_0\\ p_2 & = \frac 1 2 p_0 \\ p_3 & = \frac 1 6 p_0 \\ \vdots & \text{a pattern emerges} \\ p_k & = \frac 1{k!}p_0\end{align}$$

Spoiler:

> $\mathsf e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {k!}$

Comment: Understood! Yet, I was just asking for some hints. Can you just say a word about how works the indicator function in this case?

Comment: @Marine $\mathbf 1_{k\in\Bbb N} = \begin{cases} 1 & : k\in \Bbb N \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and it just indicates that support for $Z$ is the natural numbers.

Comment: I did this exercise again but I didn't understood why $P(X=2k)=(k+1)*P(X=2k+2)$ entails $p_{k+1} = \frac 1{(k+1)} p_k$ this time. Shouldn't it be $p_{2(k+1)} = \frac 1{(k+1)} p_{2k}$?

Comment: If $p_k \mathop{:=} \mathsf P(X{=}2k)$ then $p_{k+1} = \mathsf P(X{=}2(k{+}1))$, and so the equation is: $p_k = (k+1)\cdot p_{k+1}$ @Marine1

Comment: Do we get rid of the $2$ because we are dealing with even numbers?